# JAVA call factory methods implicitly

Tags: java, constructor, factory-pattern

I have 1 constructor and 1 factory method for my Date class. The first one just have 3 int parameter represent month, day and year. And the second one, I provide it in case user give string as one parameter to represent month/day/year.

As you can see in the main(), I forget to call parseIt, the factory method. But compiler still provide correct result. So question is: can JAVA call this factory method implicitly?

Please take a look the 1st constructor and 2nd factory methods:

```
import java.io.*;

class Date {

  private int month;
  private int day;
  private int year;

  public Date(int month, int day, int year) {
    if (isValidDate(month, day, year)) {
      this.month = month;
      this.day = day;
      this.year = year;
    } else {
      System.out.println("Fatal error:  Invalid data.");
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }

  public static Date parseIt(String s) {
    String[] strSplit = s.split("/");
    int m = Integer.parseInt(strSplit[0]);
    int d = Integer.parseInt(strSplit[1]);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(strSplit[2]);
    return new Date(m, d, y);
  }

  public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    if (year%4 != 0) {
      return false;
    } else if (year%100 == 0 && year%400 != 0) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  public static int daysInMonth(int month, int year) {
    if (month == 2) {
      if (isLeapYear(year)) {
        return 29;
      } else {
        return 28;
      }
    } else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
      return 30;
    } else {
      return 31;
    }
  }

  public static boolean isValidDate(int month, int day, int year) {
    if (year < 1 || year > 9999 || month <= 0 || month > 12 || day <= 0) {
      return false;
    } else if (day > daysInMonth(month, year)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;  
  }

  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    Date d1 = new Date(1, 1, 1);
    System.out.println("Date should be 1/1/1: " + d1);
    d1 = new Date("2/4/2");
    System.out.println("Date should be 2/4/2: " + d1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you use your implementation? Not `java.util.Date`?

Comment: Java doesn't just call methods without being told...

Comment: I didn't import java.util.* only imported java.io.*

Comment: Please add ` System.out.println(d1.getClass())` to your code check output.

Comment: @duffymo a learning exercise perhaps?

Comment: I rewrite it because it is a homework.

Comment: The only way this would compile correctly is if you've defined `... Date(String s) { ...` somewhere, or if you've imported an external Date class.

Comment: So as you say that it compiles at your end - Can you provide the whole code of your Date class? Including imports and everything? Maybe we find the error then :)

Comment: What is your package?

Comment: @talex the output is: class Date,I didn't import java.util.* only imported java.io.*

Comment: All, here is my new finding: if I comment out the first 2 lines in main(), it wont work. But if I have first 2 lines, it works.

Comment: @Patrick this doesn't add anything. You removed `d1` variable declaration. Of course it won't work,

Comment: @Patrick create new class, copy code you provided there and try to compile it (you will see there is no chance to compile).

Comment: @Zabuza  Full code updated, you can try it

Comment: @Patrick Thanks for the full code. I tried it and it does not compile: `error: constructor Date in class Date cannot be applied to given types;` at `d1 = new Date("2/4/2");` because `required: int,int,int` but `found: String`. So the reason is surely not in the code you have posted... Also your finding that it won't compile if commenting out the first two lines is not very surprising as you then have never defined what `d1` is, you do so in the first line of main `Date d1 = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not. There is no constructor which takes in a string, so it would throw a syntax error. In order to make it work, you would have to define a constructor which takes in a `String` parameter performs the same logic as the `parseIt(String)` function.

Comment: However that does not answer why "*But compiler still provide correct result*". It should, as you already said, not compile because there is no such constructor...

Comment: @Zabuza his code sample would not work, unless it was using the java.util.Date class which he already said he isn't.

Comment: The code can't compile, but probably this is not the complete code. I suppose that the main in in a different class where it imports java.util.Date. Or there is another constructor not exposed here.

Comment: @talex there is no way this snippet of code would compile unless this was a snippet of a larger file itself which we can not see, as Davide points out.